# A problem with the foreign key in pivot table Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`acl`.`report_saved`, CONSTRAINT `report_saved_user_id_foreign`
> FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into
> `report_saved` (`created_at`, `report_id`, `updated_at`, `user_id`)
> values (2020-11-25 12:06:20, 10, 2020-11-25 12:06:20, 10))

I have two models: **user** and **report** and I've created a **report_saved** pivot table which has the **report_id**, **user_id** and **timestamps** columns.

I know the naming convention for the pivot table but in this case, I want my custom pivot table to be saved as report_saved.

This is the **report** model relationship:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'report_saved', 'report_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

The **route** for attaching the saved report:

```
Route::get('save/reports/{reports:slug}/{users:id}', [LandingPageController::class,'save_report'])->name('save.report');
```

The controller method:

```
public function saveReport(Request $request)
{
        $reports = Report::findOrFail(request('reports'));
        $report_id = $posts->id;
        $user_id = auth()->id();
        $reports->users()->sync([$report_id, $user_id]);

        return back();
}
```

Can anyone give me any suggestions on what I did wrong?

Comment: Probably `$report_id = $posts->id;` should be `$report_id = $reports->id;`. In the error both `report_id` and `user_id` have value  = 10. Do you have records for user and report by those ids in the database?

Comment: Does the report with the id=10 and user with id=10  already exist on Database ?

Comment: And as @Donkarnash  said where did you got `$posts` from ?